# How to make absolute child element resize based on content, including larger than the parent element?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a dropdown menu, and want the menu dropdowns to be able to resize based on their content, while the menu "titles" remain a fixed width. So if a dropdown item had longer text than the parent title, the dropdown area would be larger than the title otherwise, the dropdown would size to the title. Text in dropdown options should not wrap I know this is doable with javascript, but can it be done using solely CSS?

So I have a menu with the following HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="title">Menu Title 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="title">Menu Title 2</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="option">Menu Option 1</div>
      <div class="option">Menu Option 2</div>
      <div class="option">Long Menu Option 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="title">Menu Title 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="title">Menu Title 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styled with the following CSS:

```
html, body, .menu{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:400px;
}

.menu-item{
  width: calc(25% - 2px);
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}

.title{
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.dropdown{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  /* width:138px; /* uncomment this for desired effect */
}

.option{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Demonstration (add `width: 138px;` to the `.dropdown` styling to see the desired effect): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXyKBJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution shortly after asking!

Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.dropdown` element forces the text to not wrap, expanding the div beyond the parent size. Adding `min-width: 100%` ensures that the dropdown will not be less wide than the parent.

I was focused on width and display properties and missed this obvious solution.